# How to correct for Heteroscedasticity in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am running a regression analysis of the housing market, where I test how the independent variables are affecting the dependent variable (Price).

I am running the following code for the OLS:

```
reg.model1 <- log(Price2) ~ Detached.house + Semi.detached.house + Attached.houses - Apartment +
  Stock.apartment + Housing.cooperative - Sole.owner + Age +
  BRA + Bedrooms + Balcony + Lotsize + Sentrum + Alna + Vestre.Aker + Nordstrand + Marka +  
  Ullern + Østensjø + Søndre.Nordstrand + Stovner + Nordre.Aker + Bjerke + 
  Grorud + Gamle.Oslo + St..Hanshaugen + Grünerløkka + Sagene - Frogner 


 reg1 <- lm(formula = reg.model1, data = Data)
```

The next step was to test for Heteroscedasticity by running Breusch-Pagan Test:

```
bptest(reg1)
```

I got the following results in the consol:

[image]

As far as I understand, since the P-value is smaller than 0.05 this means Heteroscedasticity is present.

So what I struggle with is what to do next to correct for Heteroscedasticity, I have read that there are several ways to correct this. However, everything I have tried has failed, most likely because I have done something wrong. If someone could guide me on how to correct this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: There are many ways to test for homogeneity. So, I definitely would start simple. Try testing it with an alternative method. It might be a good idea to visualize the variance. It could be one group that's causing a problem. A bee swarm plot (i.e., `ggbeeswarm`) works really well for this. If you want more information related to how to do that and what to look for, let me know. (I didn't want to provide it as an answer, because it's not really what you asked.)

Comment: You could use robust standard errors, `coeftest(reg.model1, vcov = vcovHC(reg.model1, type = "HC3"))` from the `lmtest` and `sandwich` packages or specify a different `HCX` variant.  You could also use weighted least squares if one variable seems to be causing the increased variance.  You could use heteroskedastic regression where you model the residual variance - this is probably most easily done with the `gamlss` package.  You could also use a wild bootstrap available in the `lmboot` package.